# Micromax Canvas Gold A300 "out of space"

Tags: insufficient-memory

Whenever I try to install an app, my device displays the error message "out of space", even though I have 16gb of free space. I have deleted all odex files, uninstalled all large games, and cleared the cache partition.

How can I remove this error message?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic, except insofar as they interface with your computer, See [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: This question has been migrated so that it is now on-topic here at Android.SE. I suggest you look at the [insufficient-memory tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for information that might be helpful in resolving your issue.